# Cyclic codes and roots of unity

Tags: coding-theory, roots-of-unity

I am currently reading a coding theory book and I stumbled upon the following:

Suppose we have a cyclic code $C\subseteq\mathbb{F}_{q}^n$. If $\text{gcd}(q,n)=1$ we can find an $m$ such that $n|q^m-1$ and thus $x^n-1$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. Following this, we can factorize $x^7-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ as $(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$. Notice now that $x^7-1$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$ as $\prod_{i=0}^6 (x-\alpha^i)$ where $\alpha$ is a primitive $7$-th root of unity. We then look at the code generated by $g(x)=(x^3+ x^2+1)$. **This factors into** $(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^5)(x-\alpha^6)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$.

I don't understand what is meant by *factors into* in this context. Can anyone explain?

Comment: A general way to to "this" factorization? What do you mean? Sorry, I don't understand what "This factors into" refers here. Certainly $x^3+x+1$ cannot factor into four factors. And do you really mean $x^7-11$, and not $x^7-1$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is one of the roots of $X^3+X^2+1$, then the three roots of that cubic are $\alpha, \alpha^2,\alpha^4$. Then $\alpha^{-1}$ is a root of $X^3+X+1$, and the three roots of that polynomial are $\alpha^{-1}, \alpha^{-2},\alpha^{-4}$ : less helpfully written as $\alpha^6,\alpha^5,\alpha^3$. I think if you sort out the question this would be the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I edited my question accordingly. Here, $\alpha$ is a primitive $7$-th root of unity I believe, which lives in $\mathbb{F}_2^3$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean. Why is $\alpha^{-1}$ a root of $X^3+X+1$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3+X+1$ then turn that into an equation in $\frac{1}{X}$. I emphasise that you are making a choice in notation, you must make the choice that $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3+X+1$ or you won't get the factorisation of $g$ you assert.

Comment: To b emore precise, if $\beta$ is a root of $X^3+X^2+1$ then $\beta$ is a primitive 7th root of unity, and the three roots of the cubic are $\beta, \beta^2,\beta^4$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: In case you are puzzled about the phrase *this polynomial factors into .... in a bigger field* the meaning is the same as saying that the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-3x+1$ cannot be written non-trivially as a product of polynomials with rational coefficients, but over $\Bbb{R}$ it factors as follows
$$p(x)=(x-2\cos(2\pi/9))(x-2\cos(4\pi/9))(x-2\cos(8\pi/9)).$$ The point being that none of those three linear factors have rational coefficients. This is common turn of phrase in algebra.

Comment: Yes, I realized this after reviewing the answer above. Since our polynomial splits in $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$ we can further factorize it, hence the phrase. Thanks!